# /proc/partitions lists no entries

Tags: linux, partitioning, proc

I'm trying to use the DiskIO plugin with `glances`, but it's not showing. Digging around in the code, I've found that the `psutil.disk_io_counters()` file is throwing an error, complaining about no partitions, and digging further I'm seeing that it is attempting to read `/proc/partitions`, but looking at that file all I see is:

```
> cat /proc/partitions
major minor  #blocks  name
```

So it's not listing any partitions. How can this be? The `df` command lists plenty of devices, and certainly I have access to my `/home` folder. I *don't* have `sudo` permissions -- is this possibly a cause of the error? It doesn't seem like I should require sudo for this.

I'm on SUSE Enterprise Linux:

```
> cat /etc/issue

Welcome to SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 SP3  (x86_64) - Kernel \r (\l).
```

Comment: Even as peon user you should be able to get output from `cat /proc/partitions` Provide the actual command you're running please? I'm installing glances now. Thanks. Also whatever else i need to install?

Comment: OKAY, so apparently you need su/sudo perms to run glances. Switching over to my peon account a run of glances bites it with permission denied errors. When run with su -c and passwd confirmation all is good.